# DatePicker in react js sets the same date across all rows of table. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I have multiple rows in my table, and the date picker sets the same date that is picked by the user for one row, across all rows. Kindly suggest how to solve this problem.

The date picker is being utilized in the 'Handover to Tech' Column.
[image: Table screenshot]

This is the Component Code. It is called the Tracker Chart

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

changeDate(stateName, e){

    this.setState({[stateName]: e});
    console.log(stateName + e)
    
} 

    render() {
        let filteredfiles = this.state.tracker.filter(
            (file) => {
                return file.root.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
            }
        );

        return (
            <div>
                <h2 className='text-center'>Tracker Chart</h2>
                <br></br>
                <Row>
                <div className="input-2">
                <ExportReactCSV csvData={this.state.tracker} fileName={"Tracker Chart"} />
                </div>
                <div className= "input-1">
                <input class= "form-control chosen-select" type = "text" align = "left" placeholder = "Search by Style Number Here" 
                            value = {this.state.search}
                            onChange = {this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
                        />
                        </div>
                </Row>
                <br></br>
                <div className = 'row1'>
                    
                    <table className='table table-striped table-bordered'>
                        
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Ladder Plan</th>
                                <th>Style Number</th>
                                <th>Vendor</th>
                                <th>Size Range</th>
                                <th>FOB Cost</th>
                                <th>Total Quantity</th>
                                <th>CXL Date</th>
                                <th>Handover to Tech</th>

                                
                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>

                            {
                                filteredfiles.map(
                                    master =>
        
                                    <tr key = {master.tID}>
                                        <td>{master.lp}</td>
                                        <td>{master.root}</td>
                                        <td>{master.vendor}</td>
                                        <td>{master.actSize}</td>
                                        <td>{master.totFcost}</td>
                                        <td>{master.totalQty}</td>
                                        <td>{master.cxlDate}</td>
                                        <td><DatePicker  
                        dateFormat = 'dd/MM/yyyy'
                        selected = {this.state.techHandover} placeholderText="Select Date"   
                        onChange= {this.changeDate.bind(this, 'techHandover')} 
                        maxDate = {new Date()}
                        filterDate = {date => date.getDay() !== 0}
                        showYearDropdown
                        scrollableMonthYearDropdown
                    />
                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            }

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TrackerComponent;
```

Comment: set value or date   prop of Datepicker

Answer (score 0):

return the value from changeDate function and get the value from there hope this may help you :)

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Can you please show with an example?